# Violación de segmento al acceder campo

Tags: c

Buenas. Mi objetivo es construir un array de estructuras que me relacionan un comando con un puntero a función, para lo cual he definido una estructura de la siguiente manera:

```
typedef struct function_pointers_array
{
    unsigned char * command_code;
    unsigned char * (*function_pointer)(unsigned char *, int);
} function_pointers_array_t;
```

Y inicializo el array como sigue:

```
function_pointers_array_t f_ptr_array[] = {
    { "0601", cpuUnitStatusRead },
    /*{...},
    {...},
    ...*/
};
```

Mi duda y el problema que tengo es porqué cuando hago lo siguiente obtengo una violación de segmento:

```
if (strcmp (f_ptr_array[i].command_code, cmd_code) == 0) //segmentation fault
```

Siendo `cmd_code` del tipo `static unsigned char`. El problema según he comprobado está en `f_ptr_array[i].command_code`, ¿qué hay de problemático en esto?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

---

En respuesta a @eferion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char * cpuUnitStatusRead();
unsigned char * memoryAreaRead();

typedef struct function_pointers_array
{
    unsigned char * command_code;
    unsigned char * (*function_pointer)(unsigned char *, int);
} function_pointers_array_t;

function_pointers_array_t f_ptr_array[] = {
    { "0601", cpuUnitStatusRead },
    { "0101", memoryAreaRead },
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    char cmd_code[]="0601";

    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp (f_ptr_array[i].command_code, cmd_code) == 0)
        {
            printf("\nOk");
        }
    }

}

unsigned char * cpuUnitStatusRead()
{
    //
}

unsigned char * memoryAreaRead()
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Si pones un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema será más sencillo ayudarte.

Comment: El problema podría estar en, por ejemplo, que el índice `i` es igual o superior al número de elementos, lo que haría que el código intentase acceder a memoria fuera del arreglo

Comment: No sé realmente cómo facilitar un ejemplo sin proveer todo el código. Solo decir que no es problema del índice como comentas, de hecho el mismo problema ocurre si utilizo el índice 0.

Comment: Por otro lado, dejo lo que me muestra el depurador: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Cambiando a Thread 0x7ffff6ff4700 (LWP 2230)]
__memcpy_sse2_unaligned ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:140
140 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No existe el archivo o el directorio.

Comment: Antes del `srtcmp` imprime los valores, puede ser que tengas un nulo en alguno de los dos campos

Comment: Asignas memoria en algun momento para los unsigned char *??. Podés mostrarnos esa parte?

Comment: Un ejemplo mínimo podría ser un arreglo con dos elementos y el bucle que tiene la llamada a `strcmp`. Si no eres capaz de hacer fallar ese caso es que el error está en otra parte del código

Comment: @Monpeco no es el caso, ya lo comprobé

Comment: @EmilianoTorres no he asignado memoria para el unsigned char *, debería asignarla? me resulta muy confuso en este caso

Comment: @eferion he editado mi pregunta para añadir al final el ejemplo que comentabas. Sigue provocando violación de segmento.

Comment: Se te olvidó indicar de donde sale `cmd_code`. Con ese código no queda claro que esté bien referenciado el puntero/arreglo o lo que quiera ser

Comment: @eferion editado

Comment: ¿Sabes utilizar el debugger `gdb`? es muy sencillo de utilizar, debes agregar a la compilación el flag `-g` y eso te permite inspeccionar la ejecución del programa paso a paso

Comment: @Monpeco sí, de hecho en otro comentario intenté pegar de una "manera legible" la salida del debugger donde se produce el fallo, habiendo utilizado la opción -g como dices. Sin embargo no consigo ni comprender ni encontrar información acerca de lo que me dice

Comment: Revisa con `valgrind`, a ver si te señala algo

Comment: @Monpeco voy a probarlo, gracias por la recomendación

Comment: El último código que has puesto compila y funciona perfecto. ¿ Que compilador y opciones estás usando ? si estás en Linux, ¿ que tienes puesto en LD_PRELOAD ?

Answer (score 2):

Esto debería ser un comentario, pero no es viable ponerlo como tal por su extensión y contenido.

```
memcpy(cmd_code, command+offset, 2);
```

Aquí tenemos el problema de que no sabemos qué contiene `command` ni `offset`. Aún así asumiremos que está todo bien.

Nota eso sí que estás copiando dos bytes lo cual, seguramente, no incluye el byte de terminación de cadena. Este detalle es importante porque aquí:

```
strcmp (f_ptr_array[i].command_code, cmd_code)
```

Estas comparando dos cadenas con `strcmp`. Esta función compara bytes hasta que encuentra una diferencia o un carácter nulo. En tu caso una de las dos cadenas únicamente tiene 2 bytes asignados y carece de terminador de cadena.

Cuando te pedimos que pongas un ejemplo mínimo y completo nos referimos a un código que podamos compilar y ejecutar sin problemas.

Comment: De acuerdo. He realizado un pequeño programa listo para ejecutar (disponible en la pregunta editada) que parece que no da ningún problema, sin embargo mi código no es diferente a éste y el problema persiste por más que elimines el bucle o accedas al elemento 0 del array. Seguiré probando, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Por otro lado también comentar que el valor de `cmd_code` lo he asignado manualmente en este caso ya que en mi código lo recibe de una cadena recibida por un socket. Sin embargo, he comprobado que es correcto su valor y no influye en el problema

Comment: Si el problema persiste posiblemente se deba a que el error no está donde tú crees. Ahí está la gracia de poner un ejemplo mínimo que **reproduzca el problema**. Una cosa es dónde casca la aplicación y otra el origen del problema... No tienen por qué ser la misma cosa

Comment: Eso es lo que parece... Me apunto la recomendación para el futuro

Answer (score 0):

Aquí puedes comprobarlo: http://rextester.com/PIF91009

Independientemente del tipo de parametros lo unico que debes indicar del puntero a una funcion, es el tipo de valor devuelto, en tu caso:

```
unsigned char * (*funcion)();
```

Aunque no veo que tu funcion devuelva ningún puntero.

```
#include  <stdio.h>

unsigned char a = 'A';
unsigned char b = 'B';

static unsigned char *foo1()
{
    return &a;
}

static unsigned char *foo2(int p1, int p2)
{
    return &b;
}


typedef struct mystruct
{
    int id;
    unsigned char * (*funcion)(); 
} pfunction;    

int main(void)
{    
    pfunction s []  = {{12, &foo1, "n1"},{13, &foo2, "n2"}};

    printf ("El array s tiene %d elementos\n", sizeof(s) / sizeof(pfunction));

    unsigned char *a1 = s[0].funcion();
    printf ("foo1() = %c   nombre = %s\n", *a1, s[0].nombre);

    unsigned char *b1 = s[1].funcion(10,20);
    printf ("foo2() = %c   nombre = %s\n", *b1, s[1].nombre);
}
```

Resultado:

```
El array s tiene 2 elementos 
foo1() = A   nombre = n1 
foo2() = B   nombre = n2
```

Si te fijas en este ejemplo, `foo1` y `foo2` tienen diferentes parametros, pero a tu puntero esto le da igual. Le basta con saber que es un puntero a una funcion que devuelve un `unsigned char*`

Para assignar los valores, prefiero usar la dirección de la función, aunque no es necesario queda mucho más claro:

```
pfunction s []  = {{12, &foo1},{13, &foo2}};
```

Espero que esto te sirva.

Y por si te sirve de ayuda, te dejo un enlace a la clase en c# para conectar con un PLC, que tengo publicada en [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/878194/OMRON-PLC-TCP-Interface).

Comment: Gracias por el aporte. Teniendo ese código en cuenta parece que no hay nada erróneo en mi código. Mi problema realmente está cuando intento acceder a lo que en este caso sería (usando un índice cualquiera) `s[0].id`

Comment: Estas usando este bucle `for (i=0; i<2; i++)`? O solo es para el ejemplo?

Comment: Por que si pegas tu codigo en rextester funciona correctamente.

Comment: Creo que deberias publicar el codigo real, la assignacion de punteros y el bucle que usas pafa la comparacion.

Comment: Acabo de dar con el problema, venía de otro lugar a pesar de que la ejecución se detenía ahí. Efectivamente el código del ejemplo es correcto